# Dapper DynamicParameters

Tags: sql-server-2016, dapper

I'm using Dapper with C#. I'm trying to dynamically build a query, the columns involved, and parameters, but I'm getting an error. Here is the sample code:

```
private List<string> columns = new List<string>();
private List<string> values = new List<string>();
Dictionary<string, string> parameters = new Dictionary<string, string>();

// We dynamically determine columns to add:
columns.Add("AssetName");
values.Add("@AssetName");
parameters.Add("@AssetName", "test value");

string sql = @$"insert into foo ({String.Join(",", columns)}) values({String.Join(",", values)});";

var params = new DynamicParameters(params);
connectionObject.Execute(sql, params);
```

The error I get is: Must declare the scalar variable "@AssetName".

Where have I gone wrong?

If I replace the execute line with:

```
connectionObject.Execute(sql, new { AssetName = "test" });
```

Then the query runs without error.

Note: In the dictionary I tested without and without the @ in the key.

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue. The Dictionary's values must be of type object:

```
Dictionary<string, string> parameters = new Dictionary<string, object>();
```

Also, it seems the dictionary keys don't need the leading "@".